# How to get active DFS server using Java

Tags: java, networking, filesystems, depth-first-search

I want to get the active DFS server name  from the list as shown,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhM8M.png)

Anyone knows how to get it using java or command prompt(cmd) or using dfsutil.exe?

Answer (score 0):

Using dfsutil (dfsutil.exe) you can get the details of DFS server connected in your system.

command: dfsutil /PktInfo

From the information you can find the active server for your dfs path.